# android.view.InflateException Error on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I had to repeat this question but non of the solutions are working.

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

MainActivity.java

```
package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing 
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();      

    if(map!=null){

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already two locations                
                if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();                    
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);                

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /** 
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }


                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){                   
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }

            }
        });
    }       
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";         

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
 }



// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;        
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);            

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }       
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject; 
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                points.add(position);                       
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);                           
    }           
}   


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >   

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<permission
    android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutemylocationv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutemylocationv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please help. The Google play service has been set from Android build path. The application is failing when executing

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

log

```
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149): Process: in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2, PID: 9149
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     ... 11 more
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at lzv.a(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at mcg.a(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at mcg.a(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at mbi.a(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at lxn.a(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at lxm.a(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at fnb.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: paste complete logcat error.

Comment: provided the logcat error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Error is:

as your logcat says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following
 permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
06-22 18:58:27.880: E/AndroidRuntime(9149): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

You have to add the below permisiion in your manifest file to check internet state:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

add this to your manifest and it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks.....I missed <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>